# How to copy files to postgresql db from a csv file without duplicate data?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

i am using python code with psycopg2 to automate the process of downloading csv files from a website and copying to database but i need a way that does not allow duplicate data persistence, what would be the best way around this situation?

i am currently using this code to copy:

```
COPY table_name(item ,order ,cn_main,cn_second)
                FROM '{dir.get_cn_folder()}'
                DELIMITER ';'
                CSV HEADER encoding 'ISO-8859-1';
```

Comment: You can read your csv into a Panda DataFrame object and then [drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to handle duplicate data either keep first occurrence or drop both etc. You need to set `keep` option of that function. But, before that always have a unique identifier (primary key).

Comment: You could copy into a temporary table and drop the duplicates from there when you insert into your real table

Comment: @mmustafaicer I think the problem with this approach is that this way it would remove the duplicates from the csv file, but it would still allow the persistence of data that already exists in the database, right?

Comment: @C.Nivs I thought of working with temp table, is there another way?

Comment: @GabrielCastro that is correct. I assumed data integrity is already enforced in database using primary key, but there were duplicates in csv. That was my assumption. I believe from this point, this all about DB side. You may try while inserting `... WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT primary_id FROM TABLE...)` But again for this you need to have another temp table or onboarding table before inserting.

Comment: @mmustafaicer, I think what you where looking for is found here [Insert On Conflict](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT). Or a `LEFT JOIN` from the staging table to the final table `...WHERE final.id IS NULL`.